# How to use the rest and spread operators together in a function definition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I have the following:

```
const a = (...args) =>{ return {...args}}
const abc = a('lol', 'rofl', 'lmao');
console.log('abc', abc);
```

However, this prints out

```
Object {0: "lol", 1: "rofl", 2: "lmao"}
```

But I expected

```
Object {lol: "lol", rofl: "rofl", lmao: "lmao"}
```

since

```
{lol, rofl, lmao}
```

produces the line above.

Is there a way to spread the arguments so that I can get this result?

Comment: FWIW this is not Ecmascript-6.

Comment: @lonesomeday What?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to dynamically generate objects using the short-hand syntax provided in ES6, which i'm not sure if it is possible or not.

Comment: So, using the spread/rest operator within object destructuring is experimental and is not part of the official ES2015 spec. This may be a feature that makes the spec down the road, but as of right now, it is not possible. Kyle Simpson talks about this in his "ES6: The Right Parts" workshop

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)! And `{...args}` is not the same as `{lol, rofl, lmao}`. Object spread is equivalent to using `Object.assign`: `Object.assign({}, args)`. `args` is an array (of strings), that's why you are getting this result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any build in method to do that, the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) will not work as you expected. Anyway, you can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```js
const a = (...args) => args.reduce((obj, v) => (obj[v] = v, obj), {})
const abc = a('lol', 'rofl', 'lmao');
console.log('abc', abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and computed properties.

```js
const a = (...args) => args.reduce((obj, v) => Object.assign(obj, { [v]: v }), {});
const abc = a('lol', 'rofl', 'lmao');

console.log('abc', abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
function F(...args){
  args.forEach(a => this[a] = a, this);
}
var abc = new F('lol', 'rofl', 'lmao');
console.log('abc', abc);
```

Comment: Why introduce `new`?

Comment: @Bergi Because `F` is not a factory and i am not returning anything from the constructor. But i am pretty sure you have something hidden in your pocket. Ok let's see it. :)

Comment: I mean, why use a constructor at all? It *should* be a factory function.

Comment: @Bergi, Hmm may be yes may be no. One reason might be a need to populate the `F.prototype` later.

Comment: OP wanted a plan `Object`, not something that inherits from a custom prototype